# materialize - change color of selected option in form

Tags: jquery, css, material-design, materialize

```
<div class="input-field col s6" style="color: white;">
<select>...</select>
<label>Country</label>
</div>
```

Hello,

in materialize CSS file, the text is black, and textarea are white. I reversed that because I wanted a minimalistic design. In  tag, I can easily change the color by applying inline CSS rule. The problem is that neither tag in the code (div, select and option) works.

non highlighted item

[image]

highlighted item

[image]

I want that the shown option in the select tag is shown white as every other part of the form.

materialialize forms (select option) - http://materializecss.com/select.html

link to the test site

https://jedantest.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, i went to your test site.

heres how your select is rendering on the site

```
 <input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-2161ddbe-3f6d-64f9-5861-b19cc36ce597" style="color:  white;">
```

All, i did was give `style = "color: white;"` in the `tag` and it worked ! Check it out in the picture below and let me know if it works ! :-)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I added css selector as gerardo BLANCO suggested

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following css selector to change the color of your text selection. But this will affect you entire site.

```
::selection {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Hope this is what your are looking for :)

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

::selection {
    background-color: red;
}

h2 {color: white;}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1><h2>Select all</h2>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that the question is phrased wrong. I want what is in selection (text) to be white. Not that the selection is white/red, etc.
I will edit the question now, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: So when selected the text changes color?

Comment: check the pictures, I edited the question. I want the option (text) to be white always. Every other part of the form is white text, except the select option. I only highlighted the option so you can see it is there, it exists, but the color is wrong

Comment: So you added a black background to your select?

Comment: as you can see in the first picture, there is black overlay on 70% opacity. On that overlay there is form which doesn't have background-color so it is also black with 70% opacity. black background is always there, on all elements

Comment: Can you maybe replicate it on a snippet. I am able to make a select box with a black background and white color options. But i dont think thats what you are looking for.

Comment: add  ``color: #848484`` to your ``.select-wrapper input.select-dropdown`` css selector

Comment: BTW nice scrollbar

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. Mirza answered it, but it is the same answer :)